# Succession de deux-points

Tags: ponctuation

Le *Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie Nationale* indique p. 147 qu'on doit « éviter, autant que possible, d'employer le *deux-points* deux fois de suite dans la même phrase. »

J'ai deux phrases qui me posent problème à ce sujet :

> Jésus a dit trois choses : tout d’abord : « Venez à moi » ; puis : « Prenez mon joug sur vous » ; et enfin : « Recevez mes instructions. »

et

> J’enseigne toujours aux gens : « Avant de commencer à lire, priez simplement : « Seigneur, ouvre mes yeux et fais-moi voir, ouvre mes oreilles et fais-moi entendre ce que l’Esprit voudrait me dire par la Parole. »

Dans les deux cas, le double (voire plus dans la première phrase) emploi des *deux-points* semble justifié, mais j'aimerais arriver à m'en débarasser autant que faire se peut.

Quelles formulations suggérez-vous afin de simplifier la ponctuation de ces deux phrases ?

Comment: Jésus a dit trois choses. Tout d'abord : « Venez à moi ». Puis : « Prenez mon joug sur vous ». Et enfin : « Recevez mes instructions. »

Comment: @Vincent : j'avais envisagé ce découpage, mais ça coupe vraiment en petites phrases. Ou alors, je ne met qu'un point avant "Tout d'abord" et je garde les deux-points ensuite...

Comment: C'est ce que moi j'aurais fait aussi.

Comment: Serait-ce envisageable de supprimer les ':' (sauf le premier) étant donné que les guillemets séparent bien les phrases (attention, je suis une quiche en typographie, je dis peut-être une énormité...)

Comment: @LudoMC : les deux-points sont obligatoires pour introduire une citation. Les guillemets peuvent (parfois) être remplacés par une mise en italique, voire complètement omis (c'est ce qui est généralement fait dans les Bibles, qui contiennent des citations à plusieurs niveaux), mais les deux-points doivent être présents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dans la première phrase, je ne mettrais simplement pas de deux-points avant chaque citation.

> Jésus a dit trois choses : tout d’abord « venez à moi », puis « prenez mon joug sur vous », et enfin « recevez mes instructions ».

Si tu veux vraiment présenter les citations comme des phrases complètes, une possibilité est le tiret.

> Jésus a dit trois choses — tout d’abord : « Venez à moi » ; puis : « Prenez mon joug sur vous » ; et enfin : « Recevez mes instructions. »

Dans la deuxième phrase, il n'y a pas de chaîne de deux signes deux-points, puisqu'ils ne sont pas au même niveau de citation.

> J’enseigne toujours aux gens : **«** Avant de commencer à lire, priez simplement : « Seigneur, ouvre mes yeux et fais-moi voir, ouvre mes oreilles et fais-moi entendre ce que l’Esprit voudrait me dire par la Parole. » **»**

Mais la phrase me paraît bien plus lisible au style indirect.

> J’enseigne toujours aux gens de prier simplement avant de commencer à lire : « Seigneur, ouvre mes yeux et fais-moi voir, ouvre mes oreilles et fais-moi entendre ce que l’Esprit voudrait me dire par la Parole. »

Ou encore, si l'on veut conserver le verbe « prier » le plus près possible de la citation, une tournure plus lourde :

> J’enseigne toujours aux gens qu'avant de commencer à lire, ils devraient prier simplement : « Seigneur, ouvre mes yeux et fais-moi voir, ouvre mes oreilles et fais-moi entendre ce que l’Esprit voudrait me dire par la Parole. »

De manière générale, il n'est pas interdit d'avoir plus d'un deux-points dans une phrase, mais leur enchaînement est un signe que la phrase est trop lourde et risque d'être difficile à comprendre. En fin de compte, ce n'est pas une question de grammaire mais de style.

Comment: La suggestion du tiret cadratin dans le premier cas est intéressante, et je pense retenir le style indirect dans le deuxième cas. Note que c'est volontairement que je n'ai pas fermé le deuxième niveau de guillemet, car la double fermeture est trop lourde (à moins d'utiliser des guillemets anglais en second niveau, ce que je me refuse à faire).